# Status Bar Transparent not working properly

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I am trying to make an activity with transparent status  bar and a common wallpaper. The issue is that status bar and activity are attempting to draw different backgrounds each resulting in a shabby image.

Theme xml:

```
fitssystemWindows - true
statusBarColor - @android:color/transparent
background - @drawable/backdrop
```

I will edit with exact XML later.

Image (can't upload image here): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QbRXVog08OY1doazJmaTNoeGs/view?usp=docslist_api

**EDIT 1** : Tried using the solution suggested below, still not working

Theme xml :

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

activity_main.xml :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundIV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/backdrop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

At this point the app is shown as below : 
http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QbRXVog08OX25Ib1kteDJvazQ/view?usp=sharing

**UPDATE- working code** :

Theme xml -

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/backdrop</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Activity layout xml :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should translucent statusbar and navigation bar in style file (v19 and above)

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

**Edit:**
and use this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.app.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_main" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!--  content here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried using windowTransluscentStatus also, I still get the same result, albeit it's a little improvement but not perfect.

Comment: I add a sample layout to my answer. you should put ImageView out of         layout with  android:fitsSystemWindows="true".

Comment: Still not working mate, Now Status Bar is shown in transluscent white.

Comment: Somehow, everything started working. I've accepted your answer. Thanks man.